# How can we get the background colour of a gradient image at particular point in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a gradient image and I want to get the background color at all positions where I move my mouse i.e. at a particular positions.

I can get the position of mouse so now I have to get the color at that position.

So please Guide me for this problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you made your image as a canvas named ctx then

```
var imgd = ctx.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1);
var colorhex=RGBtoHex(imgd.data[0],imgd.data[1],imgd.data[2]);
```

here is an example
http://nerderg.com/Canvas+Color+Picker